# Raspberry Pi to Airplay media server

Tags: server, streaming, media

I have a amp that you have to connect a IOS device  to inoreder to play content (AirPlay). Unfortunatley, i don't have any IOS Device to connect to it. I want to somehow connect the raspberry pi to this Airplay device so i can play music on my spotify or youtube to it.

So the way it works is that i go on my android phone, go on spotify (the rasberry pi and amp are connected beforehand). My phone detects the rasberry pi as a music output and plays music to that but the raspberry pi then plays spotify through the AMP and then the amp plays the music through the speakers.

Thanks all in advance.
~Neamus.

Comment: You mean you want to remote play audio source to raspberry pi? There's this http://www.pimusicbox.com/ that you can use tho.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about intercompatibility between Android and IOS streaming, but a good OS to install on a wifi-enabled pi is MusicBox. Just google RPi Musicbox to find out more.
This will enable you to airplay to it as you would an Apple TV or other Apple device.